# При запросе Delphi не видит символ &

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, запрос

При запросе

```
idhttp1.get('http://mysite.com/test.php?log=1111&pass=2222');
```

Delphi не видит символ `&`, вместо него подчеркивает букву `p`. А в другой новой программе видит этот символ `&`.

Пример на скриншоте:

[image]

У меня установлен RAD Delphi xe6.

Comment: @alex mrsoft, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 2):

Используя два амперсанда подряд, Windows интерпритирует одиночный амперсанд как указание на то, что следующий символ - горячая клавиша (и поддчеркивает следующий символ вместо изображения аперсанда).